# How to configure hibernate search 5.9 worker thread pool size

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I am currently working on a project where we upgrade Hibernate search to version 5.9.2 (from 3.4.2). We are using hibernate search with Lucene 5.5.5 and Spring boot 1.5. We are using hibernate version 5.2.17.

The following property was set in the entity manager config JPA properties:

```
properties.put("hibernate.search.default.worker.thread_pool.size", "5");
```

However, it seems that this property does not have any effect. During debugging, I noticed that in Hibernate Search's "LazyExecutorHolder", the executor service starts as null, and is initialized with a thread pool size of 1. The following is a code snippit from hibernate search's code:

```
package org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene;
final class LazyExecutorHolder {

/**
 * Lazily initialized; state change protected by executorStateWriteLock
 */

private ExecutorService asyncIndexingExecutor;

public void submitTask(LuceneBackendQueueTask task) {
    executorStateReadLock.lock();
    try {
        final ExecutorService executor = asyncIndexingExecutor;
        if ( executor != null ) {
            executor.submit( task );
            return; // !
        }
    }
    finally {
        executorStateReadLock.unlock();
    }
    //If not returned yet, means the executor wasn't available;
    //Needs to be started within the exclusive lock.
    executorStateWriteLock.lock();
    try {
        ExecutorService executor = asyncIndexingExecutor;
        if ( executor == null ) {
            executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 1, threadNamePrefix, maxQueueLength );
            this.asyncIndexingExecutor = executor;
        }
        executor.submit( task );
    }
    finally {
        executorStateWriteLock.unlock();
    }
}
...........
```

Was this property renamed/removed? can we configure the lucene worker thread pool size any other way? I cannot find any mention of a removal in the Hibernate Search documentation. We are currently experiencing performance degradation after upgrading Hibernate and Hibernate Search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Removal of thread_pool.size**

I removed that property myself as it was dangerous; it has been deprecated for a long time and then eventually removed. Since you're upgrading from 3 to 5 unfortunately you wouldn't have seen the deprecation warnings as they have been removed now as well.

When having the *thread_pool* property to anything higher than one there was a possibility for some write events to be reordered so this was a bug.

Yet I'm not aware of significant write performance degradations caused by this: the Lucene writing backend code has evolved quite a lot since 3.x and a single thread now is able to push larger batches of changes to the index at much higher rates, possibly saturating your IO capabilities with a single thread, so I would *generally* expect performance to be better.

**New design**

The caveat of all these changes is that clearly the overall design is quite a bit different, so any tuning options you might have inherited should be reviewed.

In particular while I believe the Lucene writing thread should be able to push for higher rates than its predecessor, the previous stages which would be responsible for loading the main entities and all its relations have been unified: there's one less stage.

**Suggestion**

Always try running the `MassIndexer` with the blackhole backend as described in the [Tuning Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.9/reference/en-US/html_single/#lucene-indexing-performance) so that you can make sure the bottleneck isn't actually in loading the data rather than writing the data in the index.

Once you're satisfied with the loading speed of data it's generally possible to bring the index writing speed close enough by using the other tunables, such as *merge_factor* and *ram_buffer_size*; if I'm wrong you can either:

- Enable Sharding, this will scale up index writing speed linearly (as long as shards don't share the same storage bottleneck - but then threads wouldn't have helped either)
- Reach out to the Hibernate Search team with some detailed profiling data, e.g. ideally you can create a new JIRA and attach a recording from flight recorder.

Comment: Thanks! We will run our performance tests with the blackhole backend as suggested. Since we were migrating from an older Hibernate search version, we used this migration guide as a reference till 5.0.0: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateSearchMigrationGuide

It would be nice if it is mentioned there for others who may be in our situation :)